# Whether the curve rotates clockwise or counter-clockwise?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

For the parametric curve
$$
\begin{cases}
x = a\cos(t) + b\sin(t) \\
y = c\cos(t) + d\sin(t)
\end{cases}
$$
How can I determine if the direction of rotation? I have got one empirical evidence that if
$$
ad - bc > 0
$$
the curve rotates counter-clockwise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The segment from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ makes angle $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis such that $$\tan \theta=\frac yx.\tag1$$ The point $(x,y)$ rotates counter-clockwise as $t$ increases if and only if $\dot\theta>0$, where $\dot\theta$ is shorthand for $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$. Calculate $\dot\theta$ by differentiating the relation (1) with respect to $t$:
$$
(\sec^2\theta)\dot\theta=\frac{x\dot y - y\dot x}{x^2},
$$ and plugging in what you know about $x$, $y$, $\dot x$, and $\dot y$.